# aws toolkit for visual studio error

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015

I have installed aws toolkit for visual studio and deployed a few test websites. But now it has started giving errors when we supply a cname of the environment. Whatever cname i may write, it says that cname is not available. I have tried even the most random of sequences of letters. If i click check availability, it says error during url validation. Kindly tell me how can i fix the problem. Find the screenshots attached. [image]

Comment: You have to give it a valid name, one that exists, specifically one you control

Comment: @Ramhound I tried that also. The ones which worked before also are not working now.